# insert records in different tabpages

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I have a problem with my form TabPageContent: 
I have to create several tabPages, each tabPage contains grids with "New" button, all  these grids point to the same datasource. 
when I click on "new" in tabPage 2 the cursor changes to tabPage1 without creating the new line on the grid of the tabPage2.

Comment: Why do you have several grids to the same datasource?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is a supported scenario: several grids using the same datasource. The reason is that Ctrl-N or New button set focus on the first grid of the datasource. Read only it works fine, it seems.

You can have several datasources with the same table, each datasource can be referenced by one grid.